# Plutus Emulator trace halting with MintingPolicyNotFoundError

Tags: plutus, minting, offchain

I have the following simple minting script:

```
{-# INLINABLE unrestricted #-}
unrestricted :: () -> ScriptContext -> Bool
unrestricted () _ = True

unrestricted_policy :: MintingPolicy
unrestricted_policy 
    = mkMintingPolicyScript
    $ $$(PlutusTx.compile [|| mkUntypedMintingPolicy unrestricted ||])

unrestricted_policy_sym :: CurrencySymbol
unrestricted_policy_sym = scriptCurrencySymbol unrestricted_policy
```

annd the following off-chain code:

```
contract0 :: Contract () Empty Text ()
contract0 = do
    Contract.logInfo @String "unrestricted starting..."
    let val = Value.singleton unrestricted_policy_sym (TokenName "ABC") 1
    let lookups = C.mintingPolicy unrestricted_policy
    let tx = C.mustMintValue val
    ledgerTx <- submitTxConstraintsWith @Void lookups tx
    void $ awaitTxConfirmed $ getCardanoTxId ledgerTx
    Contract.logInfo @String "unrestricted done!"
```

Any ideas why it's failing?

When I run in the emulator I get the following error:

```
Slot 00001: *** CONTRACT STOPPED WITH ERROR: "\"ConstraintResolutionContractError (MintingPolicyNotFound 3e112e7d22026ab6ad0e1c77c950cbb8fd5c8568bc5a63950e11bda1)\""
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this would even compile with latest `main` branch due to `mintingPolicy :: Versioned MintingPolicy -> ScriptLookups a`.

Can you update and replace `C.mintingPolicy` with `C.plutusV1MintingPolicy`

Comment: Thanks - it's working now!